# STATEMENT ERROR (Subquery returned more than 1 value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

This is my very first question. I have just took over SQL reports from the previous IT guy and I'm struggling with the query below. It suddenly stopped working two days ago and now showing:

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

It stops on line 49:

```
and (select t.[status] from [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.iSchWOScheduleLine t left join [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.WORKORDER wa on t.WorkOrderKey=wa.WORKORDERKEY where wa.workorderno=wh.WorkOrderNo)<>7
```

I understand from the error that I'm trying to update a column with multiple row data...however this query worked before... How can I fix it?

Full query:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#CCR_TimelineTable') is not null
begin
drop table #CCR_TimelineTable
end


--Populate temp table with opening inventory.
select 'Balance'as'CCStatus'
,case ss.WhseID when 'SH3' then 'FD2' else ss.WhseID end as 'WhseID'
,ss.ItemID,ss.QtyOnHand,ss.UnitMeasID,cast(cast(getdate() as date)as datetime)'Date',cast(''as varchar(max)) as'WOnum',cast(0 as decimal(10,3)) as'QtyPerCS',cast(0 as float)as'TotalWOqtyReq'
into #CCR_TimelineTable
from vdvStockStatus ss
    left join timItem i on i.ItemKey=ss.ItemKey
where ss.CompanyID='KSO'
and right(left(i.ItemID,5),2) in('PK','PC')

--Populate table with incoming purchase orders.
insert into #CCR_TimelineTable
select 'Purchas'
,case pl.WhseID when 'SH3' then 'FD2' else pl.WhseID end as 'WhseID'
,pl.ItemID,pl.QtyOpenToRcv,pl.UnitMeasID
    ,case when datename(dw,pl.PromiseDate) in ('Friday','Thursday','Wednesday')
            then dateadd(day,5,pl.PromiseDate)
        else dateadd(day,3,pl.PromiseDate) end
,pl.TranID,0,0
from vdvPurchaseOrderLine pl
where pl.CompanyID='KSO' 
and right(left(pl.ItemID,5),2) in('PK','PC')
and pl.StatusAsText='Open'
and pl.QtyOpenToRcv>0
and pl.PromiseDate > cast(getdate() as date)


--Populate table with open work orders. With iMake scheduled start times.
insert into #CCR_TimelineTable
select 'WorkOr',w.WhseID,il.ItemID,-(ww.balancequantitytoproduce*wl.MatReqPc),wos.MaterialItemUOM,ww.woschstdate,ww.workorderno,wl.MatReqPc,(ww.balancequantitytoproduce*wl.MatReqPc)
from tmfWorkOrdDetl_HAI wl
    left join tmfWorkOrdHead_HAI wh on wh.WorkOrderKey=wl.WorkOrderKey
    left join timitem il on il.ItemKey=wl.MatItemKey
    left join timItem ih on ih.ItemKey=wl.ProduceItemKey
    left join timWarehouse w on w.WhseKey=wl.WhseKey
    left join vdvWorkOrderSteps wos on wos.WorkOrderNo=wh.WorkOrderNo and wos.ItemID=il.ItemID
    left join (select wh.WORKORDERNO,sch.WOSchStDate,wh.balancequantitytoproduce from [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.iSchWOScheduleLine sch
                left join [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.WORKORDER wh on sch.WorkOrderKey=wh.WORKORDERKEY)ww on ww.workorderno=wh.workorderno
where wl.CompanyID='KSO'
and right(left(il.ItemID,5),2) in('PK','PC')
and wh.Complete=0
and ww.WOSchStDate is not null
and (select t.[status] from [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.iSchWOScheduleLine t left join [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.WORKORDER wa on t.WorkOrderKey=wa.WORKORDERKEY where wa.workorderno=wh.WorkOrderNo)<>7

update #CCR_TimelineTable
set Date= cast(getdate()as date)
where CCStatus='WorkOr' and Date<cast(getdate()as date)

--select * from #CCR_TimelineTable


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*declare @days as int
declare @PK as varchar(max)
declare @FG as varchar(max)
declare @WO as varchar(max)
declare @cell as varchar(max)
declare @desc as varchar(max)
set @days = 30
set @PK = '%'
set @FG = '%'
set @WO = '%'
set @cell = 'EGW 3+4'
set @desc = 'sain'*/

select w.WhseID,il.ItemID,id.ShortDesc as'PKDesc',wo.RoutingId,rd.ShortDesc as'FGDesc',wo.WorkOrderNo,ww.CellName,ww.WOSchStDate
    ,(select sum(tl.QtyOnHand) from #CCR_TimelineTable tl where tl.ItemID=il.ItemID and tl.WhseID=w.WhseID and ww.WOSchStDate>=tl.Date)'RunningBalance'
    ,(select top 1 tl.UnitMeasID from #CCR_TimelineTable tl where tl.ItemID=il.ItemID group by tl.UnitMeasID order by count(tl.UnitMeasID) desc)'UoM'
    ,inv.FD2,inv.FD2QC,inv.EG2,inv.EG2QC,inv.SH3,inv.SH3QC,inv.AL3
    ,(select distinct cc.QtyPerCS from #CCR_TimelineTable cc where cc.WOnum=wo.WorkOrderNo and cc.ItemID=il.ItemID)as'QtyReqPerCS'
    ,(select distinct cc.TotalWOqtyReq from #CCR_TimelineTable cc where cc.WOnum=wo.WorkOrderNo and cc.ItemID=il.ItemID)as'TotalQtyReqWO'
from tmfWorkOrdDetl_HAI wl
        left join tmfWorkOrdHead_HAI wh on wh.WorkOrderKey=wl.WorkOrderKey
        left join timitem il on il.ItemKey=wl.MatItemKey
        left join timItemDescription id on id.ItemKey=il.ItemKey
        left join vdvWorkOrder wo on wo.WorkOrderKey=wh.WorkOrderKey
        left join timWarehouse w on w.WhseKey=wl.WhseKey
        left join timItem ri on ri.ItemID=wo.RoutingId and ri.CompanyID='KSO'
        left join timItemDescription rd on rd.ItemKey=ri.ItemKey
        left join (select wh.WORKORDERNO,sch.WOSchStDate,wh.CURRENTSTATUS,mc.CellName from [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.iSchWOScheduleLine sch
                left join [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.WORKORDER wh on sch.WorkOrderKey=wh.WORKORDERKEY
                left join [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.ManufacturingCell mc on mc.CellKey=wh.MANUFACTURINGCELL)ww on ww.workorderno=wo.workorderno
        left join (select i.ItemID
        ,isnull((select vs.QtyOnHand from vdvStockStatus vs where vs.WhseID='FD2' and vs.ItemID=i.ItemID),0)as'FD2'
        ,isnull((select vs.QtyOnHand from vdvStockStatus vs where vs.WhseID='FD2QC' and vs.ItemID=i.ItemID),0)as'FD2QC'
        ,isnull((select vs.QtyOnHand from vdvStockStatus vs where vs.WhseID='EG2' and vs.ItemID=i.ItemID),0)as'EG2'
        ,isnull((select vs.QtyOnHand from vdvStockStatus vs where vs.WhseID='EG2QC' and vs.ItemID=i.ItemID),0)as'EG2QC'
        ,isnull((select vs.QtyOnHand from vdvStockStatus vs where vs.WhseID='SH3' and vs.ItemID=i.ItemID),0)as'SH3'
        ,isnull((select vs.QtyOnHand from vdvStockStatus vs where vs.WhseID='SH3QC' and vs.ItemID=i.ItemID),0)as'SH3QC'
        ,isnull((select vs.QtyOnHand from vdvStockStatus vs where vs.WhseID='AL3' and vs.ItemID=i.ItemID),0)as'AL3'
        from timItem i
        where i.CompanyID='KSO'
        and right(left(i.ItemID,5),2) in('PK','PC'))inv on inv.ItemID=il.ItemID
where wl.CompanyID='KSO'
and right(left(il.ItemID,5),2) in('PK','PC')
and wh.Complete=0
and (select sum(tl.QtyOnHand) from #CCR_TimelineTable tl where tl.ItemID=il.ItemID and tl.WhseID=w.WhseID and ww.WOSchStDate>=tl.Date)<0
and ww.currentstatus<>'Completed'
and il.ItemID like '%'+ @PK +'%'
and wo.RoutingId like '%'+ @FG +'%'
and wo.WorkOrderNo like '%'+ @WO +'%'
and id.shortdesc like '%'+ @desc +'%'
and ww.cellname in(@cell)
and ww.WOSchStDate < dateadd(day,@days,getdate())

order by ww.WOSchStDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and (select t.[status] from [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.iSchWOScheduleLine t left join [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.WORKORDER wa on t.WorkOrderKey=wa.WORKORDERKEY where wa.workorderno=wh.WorkOrderNo)<>7

The problem is that the query is now returning multiple rows.  If you run the query on it's own, it will be obvious.  The simplest way to fix this problem is to make sure only 1 row is returned by using the TOP clause, like this.

```
and (select TOP 1 t.[status] from [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.iSchWOScheduleLine t left join [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.WORKORDER wa on t.WorkOrderKey=wa.WORKORDERKEY where wa.workorderno=wh.WorkOrderNo)<>7
```

You should be aware that this is a "bad" fix because it could cause your entire query to return the wrong data.  Think of it this way... you're checking to see if the status column is a 7.  However, since the query returns multiple rows, one status value could be 7 and the other could be something other than 7.  Since you are now using a top clause, the top row could be the 7, or the top row could be the other value.

I hate to say it, but the best way to fix this query is with a complete re-write.  It's the only way to make sure your query is doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

If it finishes on:

```
(select 
    t.[status] 
from 
    [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.iSchWOScheduleLine t 
left join 
    [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.WORKORDER wa 
on 
    t.WorkOrderKey=wa.WORKORDERKEY 
where 
    wa.workorderno=wh.WorkOrderNo)<>7
```

Then the problem is that this subquery returns more than one record, so you can't compare it to a single value. You could force it to just return one value using `TOP 1`, but it depends if that's context appropriate. If you do use that, you will essentially ignore all other values from that query, and selecting the first one that comes up might not make sense!

```
(select 
    TOP 1 t.[status] 
from 
    [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.iSchWOScheduleLine t 
left join 
    [ksimakeprod01].[imake].dbo.WORKORDER wa 
on 
    t.WorkOrderKey=wa.WORKORDERKEY 
where 
    wa.workorderno=wh.WorkOrderNo)<>7
```